# Martial Arts Forms that can be practised at home without tools

Tags: training, self-defense

I am new to the world of Martial Arts, every since my childhood, learning one has captivated me. But due to lack of financial means I couldn't. Now as an adult I am still eager to learn one. I want to learn to gain the benefits of mental focus and Body control

Could you guys share a list of Martial art forms where the movement is slow with no punches like flow of water (like in yoga) instead of fall of hard rock with punches and kicking (like kungfu)? Also that can be practised at home without any tools.

The goal is to appreciate movement with breathing (again like in yoga) but in Martial Arts form that can be practised at home.

I will do due diligence from the list and get familiarised with them to make a decision myself.

Sorry, I am total noob and don't even know where to start.

Comment: You really can't learn self-defense without actually fighting with other people. Mental focus and body control are more possible, but at that point, it's not that much different from any other form of fitness. Is that sufficient?

Comment: "Easy to learn" is subjective and not easily answered. Also learning martial arts online is not much better than learning them from a book, neither is advisable. You're better off taking the number of lessons you can afford from a reputable instructor then practicing at home.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I have rephrased the question to avoid opinionated answers.

Comment: @AshokEmrys thanks, question reopened.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want strikes, like punches or kicks. They help with focus, as you must strike precisely where you mean, and at the proper distance. For example, some forms indicate one punch immediately following another, and they must punch the same position.

Comment: I can't speak to the OP, but there are a number of joint and tendon issues that are exacerbated by the sudden stops of strikes. I think that they indicated that there is not as much of an issue with a more gradual and flowing strike, such as those in *Tai chi*.

Comment: @MichaelFoster My health is not in good shape, all recent medications has made me slightly obese. I am already feeling a lot of tiredness, even jogging few minutes drains a lot of energy. Hence I am not sure if strikes would be right choice for me atleast for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, going with the obvious, [Tai Chi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tai_chi) is a slow flowing martial art that is generally practiced in a non-combative manner and without hard strikes. And there are [free resources](https://www.taichifoundation.org/videos/) to learn it. There are a number of "Chi Gong" styles that focus even more on breathing and stances. I have very little experience with them, in part because they tend to dip more into the "woo" part of martial arts of chi meridians and the like.

If you are looking for something a bit more intensive, but still flowing, you might take a look at [Capoeira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capoeira). Proper capoeira is done as a conversation with a partner, but a fair amount of the movement can be trained alone, and the body benefits of learning how to flow from pose to pose, often with turns and inversions, is excellent for the health, and will definitely work your stamina.

Comment: Those were my first two recommendations as well.  Additionally, although not considered a martial art, many forms of **yoga** have similarities with martial arts and offer some of the same benefits, as well as other benefits.